# UINavigationBar - How to change the position of UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, positioning, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I've subclassed a UINavigationBar. NavigationBar has two buttons of type UIBarButtonItem. Is it possible to move these button? For example I would like to move "left button" 50px right and  "right button" 50px left.

Is LayoutSubViews the right place to move these button?

This is the NavigationBar class (created in MT):

```
[MonoTouch.Foundation.Register("NavigationBar")]
public class NavigationBar : UINavigationBar
{
    public NavigationBar (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    [Export ("initWithCoder:")]
    public NavigationBar (NSCoder coder) : base (coder)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    public NavigationBar(RectangleF frame, string title) : base (frame)
    {
        InitializeWithStyleAndTitle(title);
    }   

    void Initialize() { }

    void InitializeWithStyleAndTitle(string title)
    {
        //- title
        UINavigationItem navItem = new UINavigationItem(title);

        //- left button
        UIBarButtonItem leftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("back", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, this, new Selector("backAction"));
        navItem.LeftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem;

        //- right button
        UIBarButtonItem rightBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("update", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, this, new Selector("updateAction"));
        navItem.RightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;    

        //- style 
        BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;

        PushNavigationItem(navItem, false);
    }

    //- selectors omitted
}
```

Comment: Is using a `UIToolBar` an option for you?

Comment: Thanks. Could I use the toolbar like the UINavigationBar? In IB I've seen that the toolbar is used "at the bottom of the screen". Is it correct to put a UIToolbar at the top?

Comment: Yes you can place a toolbar at the top of the page, and it's perfectly acceptable. NavigationBars are useful when you do multi leveled table navigation where you need to return back to the previous page/screen.

Comment: @Candide how to change the `toolbar`'s height in storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, UINavigation has a specific behavior, left and right buttons only. You should use UIToolbar instead if you need to position the buttons. Add spacers in between to adjust the positioning of the buttons.

Answer (score 3):

I'm setting the frame of a custom button and place the button in a view

```
CustomButton *menu = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 3, 35, 35)];
[menu setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliding_drawer_white_icons"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIView * menuButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 46.0f, 40.0f)];
[menuButtonView addSubview:menu];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:menuButtonView];
```